# Applying testing code with Git instead of inserting it manually

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a project with many other developers. We are using Git. I encounter the following situation frequently:

> For testing purposes, apply [some code snippet] to line x of `file.js`.

This is a problem if there are many parts of the project that need amending. And it might take time to add in the changes.

What I want the situation to be like is the following:

> For testing purposes, apply the following stash saved in our version control.

Is it possible that I can set up some sort of remote stash that the developer can apply to emulate the testing scenario?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a quick branch? They can merge the changes locally and test without pushing

Comment: If you're thinking of `git stash` itself, note that `git stash` creates a commit (well, actually at least two commits). These commits are not on any branch because only `refs/stash` points to them. That makes them hard to transver to another repository, since the transfer protocol is one of the rare places where Git actually needs a branch *name*. You might as well just use a branch.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with creating a quick branch? They can merge the changes locally and test without pushing. (from my comment)

Alternatively, you could create a patch and send it via some other medium, and apply that to the branches?